# public Event in abstract class

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action, abstract-class

I have event declared in abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public event Action ActionEvent;
}

public class MyClass : AbstractClass
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Want to access ActionEvent-- Not able to do so
        if (ActionEvent != null)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

I wanted to access this base class event in derived. Further I wanted to access this event in some other derived class of MyClass:

```
MyClass.ActionEvent += DerivedMethod()
```

Please help me understand how to work with event defined in abstract classes.

Comment: You should be able to access it, you are just improperly accessing it in the derived class. It must be part of a wire up, i.e. `ActionEvent += Myhandler;`

Comment: @EugenePodskal The OP is not asking about how you can raise base class events in the derived class.

Comment: Events are exposed mainly for "external" consumers, not for derived classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## This approach could be dangerous, see below for a better one

Events can only be raised (or checked for null apparently) from *within the declaring class*. This protection extends to derived classes.

Thus, the solution is to *re-declare* the event as an implementation of an abstract event in the base class. Then you can still use it via a base class reference as you want, and raise/use it in the derived class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract event Action ActionEvent;
}

public class MyClass : AbstractClass
{
    public override event Action ActionEvent;

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Want to access ActionEvent-- Now you can!
        if (ActionEvent != null)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

## **Correct approach**

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-raise-base-class-events-in-derived-classes) Suggests that this approach may not be handled by the compiler correctly. Instead you should provide `protected` methods so derived classes can check for null, invoke the event, etc:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public event Action ActionEvent;
    protected bool EventIsNull()
    {
        return ActionEvent == null; 
    }
}

public class MyClass : AbstractClass
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Want to access ActionEvent-- Now you can!
        if (!EventIsNull())
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Or add a null checking method to the base class, then use that in the derived class.

Comment: @Asad Sure, but you can't do that with a pure abstract base class

Comment: An abstract base class can still have concrete methods. It just can't be instantiated.

Comment: What does "pure abstract" mean? Are you talking about interfaces?

Comment: @Asad Pure abstract would be where everything possible is marked abstract. The only difference between that and an interface is that the pure abstract class could have data members (though some would argue its no longer pure at that point anyways). Plus, you can multiply inherit from interfaces :)

Comment: This seems like a completely arbitrary and not very useful definition, and if that is how you're defining pure abstract it doesn't seem relevant to my suggestion. You can still put the null checking code in a property. I don't understand how we started talking about "pure abstract" classes and what they mean anyway.

Comment: @Asad My point was that the way he defined his classes, this code seemed more reasonable. I agree that the distinction I'm making isn't terribly important/useful.

Comment: This solution is specifically discouraged by Microsoft here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx
"Do not declare virtual events in a base class and override them in a derived class. The C# compiler does not handle these correctly and it is unpredictable whether a subscriber to the derived event will actually be subscribing to the base class event."

Comment: @Sherpa Thank you for the note, I'll update my answer. I'm not sure, but it being `abstract` might change whether or not the compiler has an issue with it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  I was wondering that too... But then I'd assume that abstract will behave as virtual. Because when the base class method does not work as virtual, it would be even worse (you wouldn't get to the overridden content by definition of non-virtual method). Anyway, thanks for updating the accepted answer :)

Comment: I don't get what the point of this is - please help me understand. If you're in the derived class, what would you want to do with the event besides invoke it? In which case you'd have to use a protected method in the base class.  (I don't understand EventIsNull()... if you're in the derived class what would you want to do once you've determined that ActionEvent is not null?)

Comment: @KevinVictor You are correct in the second section that you would only call base class methods. A null check there probably doesn't make a whole lot of sense. In the original example the point was to have the event in the derived class itself (basically as part of an interface). As to when you would ever do this, I'd say very rarely

Comment: The note in MSDN is about `virtual` events. `abstract` events are handled fine.

Answer (score 17):

An often used pattern for this is something like the below (you'll see a lot of it in the classes in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace).

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    protected virtual void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MyEvent != null)
        {
            this.MyEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

You would then use it in a derived class like this, optionally extending the behaviour:

```
public sealed class MyOtherClass : MyClass
{
    public int MyState { get; private set; }

    public void DoMyEvent(bool doSomething)
    {
        // Custom logic that does whatever you need to do
        if (doSomething)
        {
            OnMyEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some custom logic, then call the base method
        this.MyState++;

        base.OnMyEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, you stole my answer. :-) You might also want to mention that `OnMyEvent` can be overridden in the derived class instead of calling it from yet another `…MyEvent` method (as long as the overriding method still calls the base class' implementation).

Comment: The question was about publishing an event from an abstract class and not consuming it.